# Reply to a message in Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-api

I want to reply to outlook messages using the microsoft graph API. However, this request returns a `503` status, with the following response:

```
 {
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorMailboxMoveInProgress",
        "message": "Mailbox move in progress. Try again later., Cross Server access is not allowed for mailbox ac4cdaf8-a061-42f8-96aa-a03f3808e7c7"
    }
}
```

I do not get this error with any other operations (like creating/ sending messages), so am baffled as to how I can make this work.

I followed this documentation and am using a message_id from a message which I sent myself:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-createreply?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

application.ReadWrite permissions are given to the app.